# Wrong shading of model loaded with *.obj file in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I load the object file [Wavefront obj file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz3oot0f5st9dqn/new_I_Profile.obj?dl=0) the normals are not correctly calculated, so the shading of model is wrong. The code that I load the *.obj model is modified from original project of loader / obj example, as can be seen from the below I scale the model before adding it to the scene, normally after those type of transformations one have to call `dirtyDisplayList`, `UpdateModel` or `RecalculateNormals`-like function to force the model to reflect current changes made to the model. In threejs the most possible functions are `geometry.computeFaceNormals();` and `geometry.computeVertexNormals( true );`

But in my case, If I call `geometry.computeFaceNormals();` and `geometry.computeVertexNormals( true );` then model totally disappears and console reports that : TypeError: geometry.computeFaceNormals is not a function OBJ_Loader.html:102

what am I doing wrong here ?

```
var I_prof =  new THREE.OBJLoader();
I_prof.load('obj/male02/new_I_Profile.obj', function(geometry){ 

    geometry.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
    geometry.rotation.x = 3.1415/2;
    geometry.position.z = -0;
    geometry.position.x = 0;
    geometry.position.y =0;
    //geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    //geometry.computeVertexNormals( true );
    scene.add(geometry);
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

It has been asked a while ago but I'll try to answer it now.

Callback function takes parameter Object3D which has attribute geometry.
On top of that, object may conatain more than one child.
You could use traverse function to get each child and modify geometry there.
So your function function(geometry){...} could look like this:

```
function(object){
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            child.geometry.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
            child.geometry.rotation.x = 3.1415/2;
            child.geometry.position.z =-0;
            child.geometry.position.x =0;
            child.geometry.position.y =0;
            child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            child.geometry.computeVertexNormals( true );
            scene.add( child );
        }
    }
}
```